# Android Retrofit cannot parse RequestBody

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, body-parser

I have trouble with a Retrofit call. I have a node js server which is working fine and I want to send a login request to it from Android.

The HTTP request expects a JSON request body. I try to create it with OkHttp3.

Here is my interface code:

```
interface ApiService {
     @POST("/login-player")
     suspend fun loginPlayer(@Body body: RequestBody): Call<PlayerApiModel>
}
```

Of course, I have more paths than this but first of all, I want this to work.

My model class, if anyone interested:

```
data class PlayerApiModel(
    @SerializedName("player_id") @Expose var playerId: Int,
    @SerializedName("_id") @Expose var id: String,
    @SerializedName("player_name") @Expose var name: String,
    @SerializedName("password_hash") @Expose var password: String,
    @SerializedName("_v") @Expose var version: Int
)
```

This is exactly the same schema as I get from the node server. But the problem is the request cannot even reach the server.

My Retrofit singleton looks like this:

```
class RetrofitInstance {
    companion object {
        private const val URL = "https://pedro.sch.bme.hu/"

        val retrofit: ApiService by lazy {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .build()
                    chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }

            val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(SimpleCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())

            val retrofit = builder
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build()
            retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly here is the problematic code part: the call.

```
val playerName = bind.root.txtPlayerName.text.toString()
val password = bind.root.txtPassword.text.toString()

val jsonObject = JSONObject()
jsonObject.put("player_name", playerName)
jsonObject.put("password", password)
val jsonBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonObject.toString())

RetrofitInstance.retrofit.loginPlayer(jsonBody)
    .enqueue(object : Callback<PlayerApiModel> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<PlayerApiModel>, response: Response<PlayerApiModel>) {
            println("${response.code()}: ${response.message()}")
            when (response.code()) {
                200 -> {
                    listener.goToMenu(playerName)
                }
                400 -> {
                    enableEditTexts()
                    Snackbar.make(bind.root, response.message(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                500 -> {
                    enableEditTexts()
                    serverErrorSnackbar()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<PlayerApiModel>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("LoginViewModel::login()", t.message)
            enableEditTexts()
        }
    })
```

The exception that I get comes to the loginPlayer() call.

This is the complete stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: neptun.jxy1vz.cluedo, PID: 14287
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object
        for method ApiService.loginPlayer
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:755)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:240)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:165)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy1.loginPlayer(Unknown Source)
        at neptun.jxy1vz.cluedo.ui.activity.login.LoginViewModel$login$1.invokeSuspend(LoginViewModel.kt:57)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class java.lang.Object.
      Tried:
       * retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
       * neptun.jxy1vz.cluedo.network.call_adapter.SimpleCallAdapterFactory
       * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:241)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:205)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:238)
            ... 12 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14287 SIG: 9
```

**Update:**
I got a suggestion to remove RxJava2CallAdapterFactory from Retrofit.

Now the bottom of the stack trace is this:

```
Tried:
       * neptun.jxy1vz.cluedo.network.call_adapter.SimpleCallAdapterFactory
       * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:241)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:205)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:238)
            ... 12 more
```

You can see here my SimpleCallAdapter, which is pretty simple (haha), I wrote this according to a tutorial, but I did not do any special thing in it:

```
class SimpleCallAdapterFactory private constructor() : CallAdapter.Factory() {

    override fun get(returnType: Type?, annotations: Array<out Annotation>?, retrofit: Retrofit?): CallAdapter<*, *>? =
        returnType?.let {
            return try {
                // get enclosing type
                val enclosingType = (it as ParameterizedType)

                // ensure enclosing type is 'Simple'
                if (enclosingType.rawType != Simple::class.java)
                    null
                else {
                    val type = enclosingType.actualTypeArguments[0]
                    SimpleCallAdapter<Any>(type)
                }
            } catch (ex: ClassCastException) {
                null
            }        }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun create() = SimpleCallAdapterFactory()
    }

}

class SimpleCallAdapter<R>(private val responseType: Type): CallAdapter<R, Any> {

    override fun responseType(): Type = responseType

    override fun adapt(call: Call<R>): Any = Simple(call)
}

class Simple<R>(private val call: Call<R>) {
    fun run(responseHandler: (R?, Throwable?) -> Unit) {
        // run in the same thread
        try {
            // call and handle response
            val response = call.execute()
            handleResponse(response, responseHandler)

        } catch (t: IOException) {
            responseHandler(null, t)
        }
    }

    fun process(responseHandler: (R?, Throwable?) -> Unit) {
        // define callback
        val callback = object : Callback<R> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<R>?, t: Throwable?) =
                responseHandler(null, t)

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<R>?, r: Response<R>?) =
                handleResponse(r, responseHandler)
        }

        // enqueue network call
        call.enqueue(callback)
    }

    private fun handleResponse(response: Response<R>?, handler: (R?, Throwable?) -> Unit) {
        response?.let {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                handler(response.body(), null)
                println(response.body())
            }
            else {
                println("${response.code()}: ${response.message()}")
                if (response.code() in 400..511)
                    handler(null, HttpException(response))
                else
                    handler(response.body(), null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage of this:

```
RetrofitInstance.retrofit.loginPlayer(jsonBody).process { playerApiModel, throwable ->
    println("Debug: ${playerApiModel?.name}")
}
```

And in the interface:

```
interface ApiService {
     @POST("/login-player")
     suspend fun loginPlayer(@Body body: RequestBody): Simple<PlayerApiModel>
}
```

**End of update**

Curious that it does not recognize the RequestBody type and instead it tries to pass java.lang.Object.

I have all the necessary dependencies in Gradle.

Comment: Can you update the post with the code of `neptun.jxy1vz.cluedo.network.call_adapter.SimpleCallAdapterFactory`?

Comment: If you set a debug breakpoint at `if (enclosingType.rawType != Simple::class.java)` does it return `null` or a `SimpleCallAdapter`?

Comment: The app does not reach that part of code before the exception.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that retrofit cannot create the call adapter, but I have no idea why.